# JPA mapping for Parent-Child with multiple same class mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have below table

```
Task
---------------------
id
name

Action
--------------------
id
name 
task_fk
target_id
```

I did following JPA mappings

```
class Task{
Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();
// other code
}

class Action{
Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
Task targetTask;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "task_fk", nullable = false)
Task task;

}
```

when I trying to save task then it failed for task which has action having target task set with persistent error

```
 if (entityInformation.isNew(task)) {
                entityManager.persist(task);
 } else {
                entityManager.merge(task);
}

Error:org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :
```

Comment: Try to show us the error

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing :

Comment: try changing `@ManyToOne` in `Action` to `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`

Comment: at least if you are populating `Task.actions` with unsaved `Action`s before saving `Task` or save each `Action` before saving `Task`

Comment: Your `targetTask` is not yet persisted / not yet exist

Comment: yeah then how should I save?

Comment: `Action` will automatically be saved when main `Task` is saved since you have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

You set your `targetTask` or other field with value that is not yet persisted/exist.
As stated in your exception:

> object references an unsaved transient instance